# Are there bombable walls in the palace?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

So, way back in the beginning of the game, *The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past*, the first time you come to the palace to save Zelda, on the first floor of the basement there are these (what look) like bombable walls, but you haven't gotten bombs yet by this point in the game. Does any one know I'd these are bombable walls, and if so, can you access them later after getting bombs?

I want to know if this was a poor choice for the wall, or an easter egg.

[image: Palace dungeon with cracked wall.]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes these are bomb holes, later on in the game once you get the power bracelet you can push a grave that leads to this area when you have bombs.

There are 3 chests containing, bombs, arrows and 300 rubies.

This YouTube video shows you it @ time 12:30

Comment: Dam you Half, you beat me by seconds! SECONDS

Comment: how do you do the YouTube embed again ><

Comment: click share and use the link i think?

Comment: @Ender yep that was it

Comment: Thank you so much! That's been driving me nuts for years.

Comment: Or click "edit" and look at the post's code.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie ty very much was wondering on how to get it embedded while keeping the time

Answer (score 1):

That wall can be bombed open, but it can also be knocked down by running into it with the dash boots. Offhand, there are a number of cracked walls in the game that can be broken down just by running into them...Look at the rounded shape of the fracture - that usually marks a wall that is dash-able.